# Are sqlite3 commands within a sqlite transaction safe?

Tags: sqlite, transactions

If I have multiple threads that can run queries on a database, will a sqlite3_step ever return sqlite busy if the step is within a transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that `sqlite3_step` needs to acquire the write lock on the database, and that this is not possible because of some other thread's read lock that is not released.

To prevent this deadlock, transactions that intend to write to the database should be started with [BEGIN IMMEDIATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) instead of BEGIN.